# View overlap after updating fragment with Asynctask

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

What i pretend is to display an indeterminate progress bar (for the moment is only an dialog for test purposes) while my second fragment is getting data and constructing the view without freezing the UI.

What i've tried:

- AsyncTask
- Loader
- Loader with AsyncTaskLoader
- Adapter (not tried but maybe its an option but i don't know how to
  use an adapter with a custom layout)

With the asynctask approach almost everything is right, but onPostExecute I've to update the fragment to do this i created an interface and in the main activity i remove the view and add the new one, but with this i created another problem my back stack is messed up so i'am out of options.

A diagram to help understand how it works:
[image]

My fragment 2:

```
public class FragTopics extends Fragment {

Object course;
ManSession session;
String courseId;
Long topicId;
String courseName;
private LinearLayout mainLayout;
private ScrollView contentScrollable;
private LinearLayout contentsLayout;
private View myView;

public FragTopics() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    session = new ManSession(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

    courseId = getArguments().getString("courseId");
    topicId = Long.parseLong(getArguments().getString("topicId"));
    courseName = getArguments().getString("courseName");

    new HeavyWork().execute();

    // Create empty view because i need to return something
    myView = new View(getActivity());
    return myView;
}

private class HeavyWork extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    final FragmentUpdater activity = (FragmentUpdater) getActivity();

    // Do the long-running work in here
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        MoodleCourseContent[] courseTopics = new ManContents(getActivity()
                .getApplicationContext()).getContent(courseId);

        MoodleCourseContent singleTopic = new ManContents(getActivity()
                .getApplicationContext()).getTopic(topicId, courseTopics);

        // This createTopics call another methods from the fragment class to
        // get the data and create views
        myView = createTopics(singleTopic, courseName, courseId, topicId);
        return null;

    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        dialog.show();
    }

    // This is called when doInBackground() is finished
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void ignore) {
        activity.updater(myView);
        dialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

My interface:

```
    public interface FragmentUpdater {

    public void updater(View param);

}
```

My main activity where the interface is implemented:

```
@Override
    public void updater(View param) {
         ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) findViewById (R.id.main_content);
         vg.removeAllViews();
         vg.addView(param);
    }
```

My layouts are created programmatic and this is structure:

```
->LinearLayout
  ->TextView
  ->ScrollView
    ->LinearLayout
```

**My main question is how to display a progress bar while fragment 2 is initialized without freezing the UI and if my above approach is correct, how to update the view in the fragment after the heavyWork is done in other words after asyncTask is done doing the background work**

After remove all view and add the new one onBackpressed will overlap my view with the previous fragments views

Comment: What is you main problem? I do not understand what you are asking for?

Comment: I updated the question, my main problem is how to display a progress bar while fragment 2 is initialized without freezing the UI and if my above approach is correct, how to update the view in the fragment after the heavyWork is done in other words after asyncTask is done doing the background work. But read everything before giving negative points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fragment is headless. So don't implement the onCreateView method. Move that code to onCreate. Then in the async task, use onPostExecute to signal the parent activity with updated information for it to display. The parent activity of this fragment can then decide how the UI should react to this information. Make sure you avoid communicating with the parent activity anywhere other than the onPostExecute (or onPublishProgress, if you're updating) method, since a) the activity can be null for a number of reasons, including a device rotation and b) these methods are gauranteed to run on the UI thread

Comment: ok makes sense but how do i set the content view for that fragment?? In another words how do i set that view created in the Asynctask to the fragment? I need to return a View thats the origin of the main problem

Comment: The Task code will reach `onPostExecute` only when the work is completed. So the UI is not being bogged down, it's just not being updated.

Communication with the main UI thread has to go through a `Runnable` you queue with that `Activity` if you're on a separate thread the `doInBackground` is running in:

`activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(...));`

You might want to look at this to understand how to integrate long running tasks with a UI in Android:
[Retaining Objects Across Config Changes](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html)